# Concatenating every other file from a list of files

Tags: unix

I have a list of files:

MD5.txt

```
8530362a272d04efef64b7f1ae0d1069  NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H3YNKDSX2_L4_1.fq.gz
9b34bdbbb17cdb1205035e24124fed1a  NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H3YNKDSX2_L4_2.fq.gz
00f8f992334458383fc1a5c7b06d403e  NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H5JY3DSX2_L4_1.fq.gz
cca0e17b3dcc1e644ec1a9a4a60a851e  NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H5JY3DSX2_L4_2.fq.gz
```

I want to concatenate the 1st and 3rd files and the 2nd and 4th like this:

```
cat NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H3YNKDSX2_L4_1.fq.gz NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H5JY3DSX2_L4_1.fq.gz >NGS35_L4_1.fq.gz

cat NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H3YNKDSX2_L4_2.fq.gz NGS35_FKDN210261811-1A_H5JY3DSX2_L4_2.fq.gz >NGS35_L4_2.fq.gz
```

I've got so far but I can't concatenate the actual files together, rather I'm just concatenating the files names...

```
#get files names
awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' MD5.txt | cut -f2 > tmp

#get sample ID
ID=$(sed 's/_.*//' tmp | head -1)

#get lines needed
sed '1q;d' tmp > file1
sed '3q;d' tmp > file2

sed '2q;d' tmp > file3
sed '4q;d' tmp > file4

#Cat files together - this doesn't work!!
cat file1 file2 > ${ID}_L4_1.fq.gz
cat file1 file2 > ${ID}_L4_2.fq.gz

rm file* tmp
```

I'm sure there is probably a one liner... go easy, I'm a clinician not a bioinformatician!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `file1`, `file2` etc. are just the filenames you want to concatenate together, so you need another layer of `cat` in order to get to the contents.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#get files names
awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' MD5.txt | cut -f2 > tmp

#get sample ID
ID=$(sed 's/_.*//' tmp | head -1)

#get lines needed
cat $(sed '1q;d' tmp) $(sed '3q;d' tmp) > ${ID}_L4_1.fq.gz
cat $(sed '2q;d' tmp) $(sed '4q;d' tmp) > ${ID}_L4_2.fq.gz

rm  tmp
```

As an aside, I'm surprised that you're able to cat together .gz files and have the resulting file still "work", but that does work for me, so I've learned something, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but I am sure there is a more elegant one..!

```
#!/bin/bash

#get file names
awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' MD5.txt | cut -f2 > tmp

#get sample ID
ID=$(sed 's/_.*//' tmp | head -1)

#get lines needed
file1=$(sed '1q;d' tmp)
file2=$(sed '3q;d' tmp)

file3=$(sed '2q;d' tmp)
file4=$(sed '4q;d' tmp)

#car files together
cat $file1 $file2 > ${ID}_L4_1.fq.gz
cat $file1 $file2 > ${ID}_L4_2.fq.gz

rm tmp
```